# maven compiles with wrong src path in pom.xml but sonar does not

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I was trying to build a branch which had the structure like this:

docs  (Directory)

mobile  (Directory)

The pom.xml is in mobile folder.
When I was compiling with maven, it works fine but sonar was failing with the error
 **"The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration"**
Please refer my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421694/correctly-setting-sonar-sources-in-jenkins-plugin)

To resolve I tried to provide the **-Dsonar.sources** option with **mvn sonar:sonar** command but in  vain.

In the pom I changed **src** into **mobile/src** and the Sonar build was success.

My question is how is that by changing the path in pom.xml worked, but putting -Dsonar.sources=mobile/src  (OR mobile/src/main/java OR absolute path as suggested by others) option in command line did not worked?  Also how is maven successfully compiling the code with seemingly wrong path for src in pom ?

Comment: By `maven successfully compiling`, do you mean, you can see classes getting created or just `compilation` going through without errors, but nothing getting compiled?

Comment: classes are getting generated

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
<build>
 <sourecDirectory> "the path to sources " </sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

at your main pom.xml and all should work.